# Bootstrap 3 - columns equal height with flexbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am trying to get a row with equal height columns regardless of content with the link at the bottom with all columns. Here is a [JS BIN](https://jsbin.com/yisafit/edit?css,output) and code is below.

```
<div class="container">

    <h4 class="report_list__title">Activites</h4>
    <div class="row report_list">

        <div class="col-xs-3 report_list__item">
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 1</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 report_list__item">            
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 2</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>            
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 report_list__item">            
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 3</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>            
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 report_list__item">
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 4</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <h4 class="report_list__title">Marketing</h4>
    <div class="row report_list report_list--last">
        <div class="col-xs-3 report_list__item">
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Marketing 1</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


.report_list {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.report_list--last {
    border: none;
}

.report_list__title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.report_list__item {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.report_list .report_list__item a {
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `margin-top: auto;` instead for the last anchor it will be positioned at the bottom.

Stack snippet

```css
.report_list {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.report_list--last {
    border: none;
}

.report_list__title {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.report_list__item {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.report_list .report_list__item a:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;                      /*  push to bottom  */
    align-self: center;                    /*  hor. center  */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    <h4 class="report_list__title">Activites</h4>
    <div class="row report_list">
        
        <div class="report_list__item">
            
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 1</a>
            <p>List and filter all sales property viewings.</p>
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="report_list__item">
            
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 2</a>
            <p>List and filter all sales property valuations.</p>
            <p>List and filter all sales property valuations.</p>
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="report_list__item">
            
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 3</a>
            <p>List and filter all sales properties with missing EPCs.</p>
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="report_list__item">
            
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Activity 4</a>
            <p>List and filter all sales property offers.</p>
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <h4 class="report_list__title">Marketing</h4>
    <div class="row report_list report_list--last">
        
        <div class="col-xs-3 report_list__item">
            
            <a href="#" class="report_list__item_heading">Marketing 1</a>
            <p>List and filter all sales property viewings.</p>
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Cheers @LGSon. Why is it margin-top and not the flex-end? I actually think I saw this a year or two ago and forgot until I saw your answer.

Comment: Ahh is there any way to get the button to appear as normal and not stretch out too?

Comment: @PierceMcGeough `align-items: flex-end` should be set on the flex container, if to use on the flex item, it should be `align-self`, but for a flex column direction this means left/right (along cross axis), hence auto margin is needed here.

Comment: @PierceMcGeough What do you mean _button as normal_?

Comment: the button is currently stretched, I think due to .report_list__item {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}. The button should only be the width of the text needed.

Comment: I can get it with `margin: auto auto 0 0;` but i can't help but feel this is too hacky.

Comment: @PierceMcGeough Now the initial `align-items` comes into play, which defaults to `stretch` and the reason the button does that. Updated my answer with its flex item property, `align-self`.

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks ever so much

Answer (score -1):

I think if you add this to the `.report_list__item` it might work:

```
justify-content: space-between;
flex:0 0 200px;
```

This article is pretty good too for Flexbox layout examples:
https://medium.com/coderbyte/a-guide-to-becoming-a-full-stack-developer-in-2017-5c3c08a1600c